# How do I fix "storage class specified for parameter" error in isr.h?

Tags: operating-system, interrupt

I'm working on my own operating system called *Choacury*, I am trying to make a working IRQ and while it was working somewhat fine, whenever I try to compile `timer.c`, it spat out [this](https://pastebin.com/7GNbSqat) in the terminal, and refuses to make the binary which means no ISO file for it.

The compiler worked fine and didn't give off ISR.H errors without timer.c being linked and compiled.

If your curious, heres the code for timer.c:

```
`#include "timer.h"
#include "vga.h"
#include "utils.h"
#include "isr.h"

u32 tick = 0;

static void timer_callback(registers_t regs) {
    tick++;
    k_printf("Tick: ", 0);
    
    char tick_ascii[256];
    // int_to_ascii(tick, tick_ascii);
    // k_printf(tick_ascii);
    // k_printf("\n");
}

void init_timer(u32 freq) {
    /* Install the function we just wrote */
    register_interrupt_handler(IRQ0, timer_callback);

    /* Get the PIT value: hardware clock at 1193180 Hz */
    u32 divisor = 1193180 / freq;
    u8 low  = (u8)(divisor & 0xFF);
    u8 high = (u8)( (divisor >> 8) & 0xFF);
    /* Send the command */
    port_byte_out(0x43, 0x36); /* Command port */
    port_byte_out(0x40, low);
    port_byte_out(0x40, high);
}`
```

I have tried commenting out some of the print functions of `timer.c` but no progress.

Also if your wondering what timer.h and isr.h is, here it [is](https://pastebin.com/dSSWuxWa).